# Can PhpStorm autocomplete methods in Drupal::service?

Tags: 8

Are there anyway to get phpStorm to autocomplete **\Drupal::service("xxxx")->..**

[https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!core.services.yml/8 For complete reference of Drupal8 service [1](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!core.services.yml/8)

For example
Typing .. \Drupal::service("config_factory")->g should show "get" in autocomplete popup list

This would be very handy for services from third-party developer also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The auto-complete suggestions are based on the type of return value documented in the `\Drupal::service()` doxygen comment. Since the method may return service of any kind the type of return value is *mixed*.

That means auto-complete is not possible unless you explicitly specify type of the service.

```
/** @var \Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactoryInterface $config_factory */
$config_factory = \Drupal::service('config.factory');
```

For some particular services you can use dedicated  methods like `\Drupal::configFactory()` or `\Drupal::config()` which have properly documented return value.

Notice that generally dependency injection is more preferable method for accessing services.

Comment: Are you saying that Drupal::service('xxx')->yyyy()... should be avoided if possible?... So why would Drupal invent this services.yml wheel for developes??  Obviously, direct call is easier to debug.

Comment: Nope @Vorapoap, not having automatic IDE type hinting should never be a reason not to use a method (IMO), especially when a quick comment will enable it. Drupal didn't invent the service container BTW, Symfony did. Drupal just uses it because it's tried and tested

Comment: @Vorapoap, You cannot inject a service into a PHP function (for instance a hook in module file).  In such case Drupal::service() is appropriate.

Comment: IMO, JetBrain team can create a plugin to preparse any services.yml, and have all services mapped to Service Classes.  Then with a bit more effort on string detection,  auto completion/suggestion will be possible. BTW, I notice that they have autosuggestion for routing name but I never get it to work though

Answer (score 3):

There is [PHPStorm metadata](https://www.drupal.org/project/phpstorm_metadata) now.

Install it, run `$ drush phpstorm-metadata:generate` and it will generate a `.phpstorm.meta.php` file in your web root for PhpStorm to match services to their corresponding classes and now autocompletion works. What a bliss!

> This module allows to export PHPStorm Advanced Metadata in order to
>   get autocomplete functionality and return type information for next
>   calls:
>
> - `Drupal::service()`
> - `ContainerInterface::get()`
> - `EntityTypeManager::getStorage()`